# How to acces the same datafile from to different DigitalOcean servers?

Tags: r, digital-ocean

The title more or less says it all - how do I acces the same Rdata file, from to different DigitalOcean droplets?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, so I can only offer you generic advice.

In general, an Rdata file (created using `save`) needs to be physically transported to each node to be used. If you are using multiple droplets (servers), you could have a central node cut up your data in pieces, and send each of the droplets a piece of data to process. Alternatively, you could put the data in a database accessible via the Internet. Then, each droplet could be told what it needs to read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes, it is quite vague - sorry for that. I have thought about saving the Rdata file on dropbox and then calling it from the different droplets I use. However what I was aiming for, was a way to use digitaloceans API to somehow call the datafile from other droplets?